# Ext.data.Store.loadRawData reading only last record

Tags: json, extjs4.2

I am trying to read a JSON response into Ext.grid.Panel using Ajax . However, Grid is showing only last record out of 5 results, can anyone please help:

JSON Response:

```
 {"tweets":[{"text":"T 1156 -On #KBC the 1 crore winner Taj Mohammed Rangrez ... requires great maturity and guts to leave #KBC at  1crore and 2 lifelines unused","date":"1379273177","user":"\/SrBachchan","id":"145125358"},{"text":"T 1156 -Taj Mhammed Rangrez wins 1 crore rupees at #KBC .. what a game he played .. and he, such a beautiful human !! write in to #KBC","date":"1379272401","user":"\/SrBachchan","id":"145125358"},{"text":"T 1156 -SO ... what did you think of the 1st Crorepati winner on #KBC ... send in your comments to me through the #KBC tag .. love ya !!","date":"1379272302","user":"\/SrBachchan","id":"145125358"},{"text":"T 1156 -The last 2 tweets should have been numbered T 1156 ... apologies !!","date":"1379272226","user":"\/SrBachchan","id":"145125358"},{"text":"T 1155 -Ashok Chakradhar writes : \u092a\u094d\u0930\u0936\u094d\u0928 2. \u0905\u0928\u093e\u0921\u093c\u0940 \u091c\u0940, \u0906\u091c\u0915\u0932 \u0926\u0942\u0938\u0930\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u093e \u092d\u0932\u093e \u0915\u0930\u0928\u0947 \u0935\u093e\u0932\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u094b \u092c\u0947\u0935\u0915\u0942\u092b \u0938\u092e\u091d\u093e \u091c\u093e\u0924\u093e \u0939\u0948\u0964 (cont) http:\/\/tl.gd\/n_1rmfn3e ","date":"1379270895","user":"\/SrBachchan","id":"145125358"}]}
```

Ext Code:

```
var tweetModel = Ext.define('Tweet', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [

                { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'date', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'user', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'id', type: 'string' }

            ]
            });

var v= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: tweetModel,
         proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'tweets' 
                } 
            }

});
var trailerPanel= Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Tweets List',
    store: v,
    columns: [
        {text: 'Text',  dataIndex:'text',filterable: true},
        {text: 'Date',  dataIndex:'date',filterable: true},
        {text: 'User',  dataIndex:'user',filterable: true},
        {text: 'ID', dataIndex:'id',filterable: true}
    ],
    width: 1000,
    forceFit: true,
});

var frmTrailerPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Hashtag Form',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        itemId:'hashtag',
        name: 'hashtag',
        fieldLabel: 'Enter Hashtag',
        allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
    }
    ],
    //renderTo:ext.getBody(),
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Search',
        handler: function() {
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
               if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: '../../assignment/index.php',
                    waitMsg: 'Fetching tweets...',
    success: function(form, action) {
  },
    failure: function(form, action) {
            var myData = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                v.loadRawData(myData,true);
                trailerPanel.render(Ext.getBody());
    }
                });
            }   
        }
    }
    ]
});
```

Output:
[image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because all 5 have the same `id` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot CD ! you just saved my life :)